# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.aiplatform.gapic' has no attribute 'MatchingEngineServiceClient'

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

```
# Initialize client
client = aiplatform.gapic.MatchingEngineServiceClient()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 # Initialize client
----> 2 client = aiplatform.gapic.MatchingEngineServiceClient()

AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.aiplatform.gapic' has no attribute 'MatchingEngineServiceClient'
```

try to initialize the matching engine client from vertex `AI`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following line to the top of your code:

```
import google.cloud.aiplatform.gapic.v1beta1 as aiplatform
```

and then

```
client = aiplatform.MatchingEngineServiceClient()
```